# Confirmation page - Restrict access unless using link sent to email for registering an account

Tags: php

Fairly new here... just need a bit of help if anyone would be so kind?

So I have a confirmation form but I only want people that are using a link sent from the registration form. I tried sending a URL query in that link:

website.com?token=token

Then if you open the confirmation page I check if that token is set, proper length, and pattern, then check it against a database, and if they were already verified.

... the problem I have is submitting the form on that page.  I’ve already checked the URL query so the form doesn’t include an input for the token I only ask for a username and password.

Since the code is somewhat long the error SEEMS to comes down to:

```
if(isset($_POST(‘confirm’)){
// Do form stuff
}elseif(isset($_GET(‘token’)){
// Do token stuff
}else{
// Kick off page
}
```

The button on the form is 100% named right and the method is post on the form but as soon as I submit I get the //kick off the page error message. I also get kicked off the page without a valid token so I don’t understand what’s not working (also not really sure if this is a good way to do this?)

Comment: In addition to `POST` being an array rather than a method (meaning you'd need square brackets), you also appear to have special quotation marks there. Instead of `$_POST(‘confirm’)` and `$_POST(‘token’)`, try `$_POST["confirm"]` and `$_POST["token"]` :)

Comment: Enable error reporting, should what @Obsidian pointed out be what the issue may be; we don't know that for certain. That will show you some form of parse error. The ticks may have been confused with regular `'` quotes.

Comment: Thank you, I will check again tomorrow this was my failure of an attempt to write out my code on my phone.... I probably should’ve just waited and pasted the code directly... Fairly certain I did use square brackets in the original but I am only using single quotes...